# History of Moti Masjid

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-india, building, islamic-history

Who built the Moti Masjid?

Google says it's [Sahjahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shah_Jahan) who built it, but Wikipedia says it was built by [Jahangir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahangir).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moti_Masjid_(Red_Fort) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moti_Masjid_(Agra_Fort) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moti_Masjid_(Lahore_Fort)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that both are correct.  It's just that they are referring to different buildings. The term *Moti Masjid* simply means "Pearl Mosque".

---

The [Moti Masjid (Agra Fort)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moti_Masjid_(Agra_Fort)) "Pearl Mosque" in Agra was built by  the Mughal emperor [Shah Jahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shah_Jahan) in the 17th century.

[image: Moti Masjid, Agra]

- Image source - [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Moti_Masjid,Agra.jpg)

The [Moti Masjid (Lahore Fort)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moti_Masjid_(Lahore_Fort)) "Pearl Mosque" inside the Lahore Fort was built by Mughal emperor [Jahangir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahangir) earlier in the 17th century.

[image: Moti Masjid, Lahore]

- Image source - [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Moti_Masjid_lahore_fort.jpg)

---

Wikipedia notes that there is also the [Moti Masjid (Red Fort)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moti_Masjid_(Red_Fort)) "Pearl Mosque" built inside the Red Fort complex in Delhi, and which was built by the Mughal emperor [Aurangzeb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurangzeb) from 1659-1660.

[image: Moti Masjid, Delhi]

- Image source - [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fuerte_Rojo_Delhi_3.JPG)